# "just receive" Vs "just received"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs

Which is the correct English usage and why?

> 1. "I just receive my package"

> 2. I just received my package"?

Comment: The word "just" followed by ***any** present tense verb form* can ONLY / JUST / MERELY have that meaning *(All I do is **receive** my package; I don't open it or do anything else with it).* When followed by a ***past** tense verb*, it can also have the sense of ONLY **VERY RECENTLY** *(I received it **just a moment ago**)*.

Answer (score 2):

They both correct grammar.

The first is present tense. The second is past tense.

If you get the same package every day and you receive it everyday, but you don't open it or do anything else then you would say (1)

If the package came 5 minutes ago then this is the recent past and you would use the past tense and say (2)

The meaning is different.    The meaning of the first one is very strange. The meaning of the second one is normal.

You should use the second one.

You can also use the present perfect for past actions that affect the present:

> I have just received the package.

In British English the present perfect would be the most natural verb form to use.

Comment: Since you've explicitly raised the alternative interpretation for the *present* tense alternative, maybe it's worth pointing out that the same "contrived" interpretation could apply with the past tense - *"I just **received** the stolen goods, your honour. I never sold them on to even more crooked dealers".*

Comment: Why can I only use it if I get the same package every day and receive it everyday? Why does it matter if I don't open it or do anything else then only I say 1.?

If the package came 5 minutes ago or just came, isn't it present tense and can't I use 1.?

Why is the meaning of 1. very strange and the meaning of 2. normal?

Comment: If it just came it isn't present. It is past, and you use past tense. The meaning of 1 is strange because you don't receive the same package every day. It is not realistic.

Comment: It might be worth also saying that the present perfect is very useful

Comment: What is counted as present tense, past tense and present perfect tense? I am not fluent in tenses.

Answer (score 0):

Which is the correct English usage and why?

1. I just receive my package.

Grammatically, it is correct.
In reality, is not usual to regularly do this action.... Which the present simple means, actually.

2. I just received my package. Am.E.

   I've just received my package. Br.E.

The same meaning: the result of the action (receiving the package) is that I already have it. It happened in the very recent past (just), and here is my package in my hands...